# Python : optimization/multiple if then on less lanes?

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying some optimisation on my code and I struggle with multiple if then statements. The point is to update SQL database with psycopg2 and I must set some variables with "None" to be "null" in SQL.

If I do if/elif/elif, the script will leave on the first valid condition but I want every condition to be checked, here is the script :

```
if variable_a == "":
    variable_a = None

if variable_b == "":
    variable_b = None

if variable_c == "":
    variable_c = None  

if variable_d == "":
    variable_d = None
```

Is there a way to do it in one row such as assigning multiple variable values?

```
variable_a, variable_b, variable_c, variable_d = "", "", "", ""
```

Bonus question : the whole point of the script is to srap data from website, getting the desired data with ReGex then updating SQL databases. The full script is about 24.000.000 iterations with all the code inside a "for i in" loop, i'm looking for a way to optimize it because it takes actually 12 days running... Do you have any tips ? Libraries ?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: "but I want every condition to be checked" - so that's what your posted version actually do

Comment: I know, but is there a shorter way to do it than 4 "if then" ? Like in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a simplified function for that case:

```
var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d = "", "", "", ""

to_None = lambda v: None if v == "" else v
var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d = to_None(var_a), to_None(var_b), to_None(var_c), to_None(var_d)

print(var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d)
```

---

```
None None None None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like

```
variable_a = variable_a or None
```

for every veriable. Also if your variables are in an array, you can do this with list comprehension:

```
arr = [i or None for i in arr]
```